# SCSS silent class output as helper class

Tags: sass

The extend normal class function will group the class name that i do not want.

So i use SCSS silent class.

```
%red {
  color: red;
}

.someclass {
  @extend %red;
}
```

but how can the silent class output as helper class for html late use?

```
.red {
  color: red;
}

<h1 class="red">red title</h1>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is a question.  You clearly understand how extends work, so do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
favorite
```

The extend normal class function will group the class name that i do not want.

So i use SCSS silent class.

```
%red, .red {
  color: red;
}

.someclass {
  @extend %red;
}
```

And you can use the classname `red` on the HTML